# Hadoop: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bogotobogo.hadoop.WordCount

Tags: hadoop

I am very new to hadoop and I am following along with this tutorial: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Creating_Wordcount_Maven_Project_Eclipse_MapReduce.php

I have built with Maven and created jar file. Now when I run the jar using

```
hadoop jar hadoop/target/wordcount-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.bogotobogo.hadoop.WordCount input/wordcount.txt output
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bogotobogo.hadoop.WordCount
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I am not sure if it has something to do with classpath or hadoop_classpath.

What could be the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide screen shot of your project structure ?

Comment: Have you created your program in com.bogotobogo.hadoop package??